# how to change particular string from a paragraph in ios?

Tags: html, ios, string

```
<a idref="_5AD480AC_7D6C_4AA6_B003_F1C5F38F4D15" 
   sectionid="n1e14b600d6dec639" internal="true" type="text" 
   slug="histologie/quergestreifte+muskulatur+histologie" link="" ui-
   sref="main.learn.content({slug: 
   'histologie/quergestreifte+muskulatur+histologie', '#': 
   '_5AD480AC_7D6C_4AA6_B003_F1C5F38F4D15'})" webtrends-track-on-click="
   {'WT.i_module': 'Textlink - Intern'}" >
   ultrastrukturelle Aufbau der Myofilamente
</a>
```

I have above content as response. I just want to change that string to below.

How to get:

```
href="/lernmodule/histologie/quergestreifte+muskulatur+histologie#_5AD480AC_7D6C_4AA6_B003_F1C5F38F4D15"
```

from the above string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        strContent=[strContent stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"', '#': '" withString:@"'#"];
             strContent=[strContent stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'})\" web" withString:@"\" web"];
           strContent=[strContent stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"({slug: '" withString:@" \" href=\"/lernmodule/"];
        strContent=[strContent stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"\"#" withString:@"#"];
```

Answer (score 1):

If the format of your response is specific like you shown in your question then below code will work for you:

```
    NSString *match = @"internal";
    NSString *postTel;
    NSString *preTel;

    NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:str];
    [scanner scanUpToString:match intoString:&preTel];

    [scanner scanString:match intoString:nil];
    postTel = [str substringToIndex:scanner.scanLocation];

    NSString*requiredString=[[postTel substringFromIndex:3] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"internal" withString:@""];
```